How to fix ubuntu 24.04 VM installation on windows10?
Because I have severe issues with an ubuntu VM installation on windows 10 I decided to install a ubuntu VM again, this time version 24.04. Of course it did not work!
After having started the ubuntu UI I see the following screen:

and one second after I see this screen:

And after one second it is back to the first screen and so on.
This does not happen all the time, but maybe every 5th time I startup the VM this happens. Solution: restart. Sometimes I have to restart a couple of times!
Is there a BETTER solution?
Configuration:

Base memory: 14 GB
Chipset: PIX3
TPM: None
Processor: 4
Execution Cap: 100%
PAE/Nx disabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-v disabled
Video Memory: 128 MB
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
3d Acceleration disabled

The host information:

hp EliteBook 840 GB
Windows 10 10.0.19045 Build 19045
RAM: 32 GB
i7-1185G7 processor (4 cores)

Display info:
Name    Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9A49&SUBSYS_880D103C&REV_01\3&11583659&2&10
Adapter Type    Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics Family, Intel Corporation compatible
Adapter Description Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
Adapter RAM 1.00 GB (1’073’741’824 bytes)
Installed Drivers   C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igdumdim64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igd12umd64.dll
Driver Version  31.0.101.4887
INF File    oem310.inf (iTGLD_w10_DS section)
Color Planes    Not Available
Color Table Entries 4294967296
Resolution  1920 x 1080 x 60 hertz
Bits/Pixel  32
Memory Address  0x3E000000-0x3EFFFFFF
Memory Address  0x0000-0xFFFFFFF
I/O Port    0x00003000-0x0000303F
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967243
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\IIGD_DCH.INF_AMD64_DA775D7ECF291310\IGDKMDN64.SYS (31.0.101.4887, 48.40 MB (50’748’616 bytes), 27.11.2023 13:23)

Sometimes I have to restart the VM like 7 times in row until it finally works!!!
